# Htop showing multiple java processes with different pids

Tags: java, process, jvm, htop

Htop on my linux machine shows many "processes" after launching one java program/JVM. I do understand that the JVM runs multiple
threads (for the actual program, for garbage collection, etc).

But how come htop lists them as multiple processes with different pids. What exactly are those processes?

Comment: On old versions of Linux, multiple thread were implemented as multiple processes.  Of course, I don't imagine anyone uses such an old OS anymore. ;)

Comment: I've been wondering about this forever - I just attached an example to the original post - hope this is ok.

Comment: You may need to zoom in on your browser to make it out, apparently.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Actually, it's just that htop by default shows each thread as a separate process.  You can add the line `hide_userland_threads=1` to your `~/.config/htop/htoprc` file to show only one line.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps

Comment: Hi, htop author here. Recent versions do not use `~/.htoprc`, but rather `~/.config/htop/htoprc`, which is the XDG-compliant path. Also, I know it's not a very Unix thing to say, but I discourage direct editing of the htoprc file; consider it an internal tool -- please edit through the Setup screen from within htop (F2). The htoprc format is not documented and subject to change in between releases (htop handles the conversion internally when the format changes.)

Comment: After F2, the actual option to hide threads is in _"Display options"_ and is called _"Hide userland threads"_. Pressing `H` also toogles this option from the main screen.