# Node.js spawns multiple processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, nodemon

I got a little bit confused about my node.js application. As far as I thought, node.js runs in a single process. However if I start my application by invoking `node app.js`and monitor it with htop, I can see 4 sub-processes running, where I'd expect only one to be.

[image]

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),

    objects = require('./objects'),

    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),

    pinLayout = objects.pinlayout,

    // utils
    util = require('util'),
    wiringPi = require('wiring-pi'),
    winston = require('winston'),
    async = require('async');


// Logger - winston
var log = new(winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.Console)({
            colorize: true,
            timestamp: true
        }),
        new(winston.transports.File)({
            filename: './log/app.log'
        })
    ]
});

// WiringPi
wiringPi.setup('gpio');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());

app.use(require('less-middleware')({
    src: __dirname + '/public',
    force: true,
    compress: true
}));

app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// 404 Page
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('404.jade', {
        title: "404 - Page Not Found",
        showFullNav: false,
        status: 404,
        url: req.url
    });
});

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler({
        dumpExceptions: true,
        showStack: true
    }));
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code? Which modules do you use? We need more information.

Comment: the app itself that you run is a single process - but you can spawn additional processes from that app if needed.  Paul is right - please share more details

Comment: Hey guys, I just did and removed the routes only, besides that I have only some constants and functions declared, but during startup nothing actually happens more than starting the webserver and waiting for requests.

Answer (score 9):

Although your code runs in a single thread, node.js uses a thread pool (mostly) for file system operations. This is needed because there are no async APIs for fs.

For example, when you call `file.readFile`, you will go through [`Read()`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.21/src/node_file.cc#L723), which will call:

```
ASYNC_CALL(read, cb, fd, buf, len, pos);
```

`read` is the blocking unix [read(2)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?read+2). This will run in a thread until it completes. These are the threads you are seeing.

Comment: To complete this answer, here is a [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12978866/2137601), which shows how to configure `htop` in order not to show the different threads of a single processus.