# sails.js multiple child process, what are those? Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sails.js, htop

By running sails with forever or calling it directly with `node app.js --prod`, according to `htop` i have a 4 child process that look like clones under it.

[image]

If i leave out the `--prod` argument, i get an equal quantity of grunt processes.
As you can see they all have the same amount of memory used, different PID and different TIME+ readings.

I'm pretty sure sails its not auto clustering, or is it? This is a single core machine (virtual), so i have no idea what are those processes, or is it an error in htop?

According to this question [htop-showing-multiple-java-processes-with-different-pids?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017597/htop-showing-multiple-java-processes-with-different-pids?rq=1)

htop shows threads as different process, but isn't node single threaded? If those are threads where are they comming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threads you see using htop is userland threads(user's thread) but when you run your application in cluster mode(say 4 instances),it makes kernel thread.
[**more on user threads**](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_user_level_threads_and_kernel_level_threads)

when you hide userland threads then whatever you see is kernel thread.while running application in cluster mode you will create multiple kernel threads of an application.And for each application's kernel thread there are several userland threads associated with it.

**(for htop you can hide userland thread by F2 and display options)**

please see the screen shots for explanation.

[**four instances of my app in cluster mode since number of cores==4**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23zD1.png)
[image]

[**ps commands showing kernel threads only**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rlc6.png)
[image]

[**htop showing kernel threads only**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOzTx.png)
[image]

[**htop showing kernel threads along with userland threads**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzTAp.png)
[image]

**In last screenshot you see a few kernel and userland's threads but there are more.
I mean for each kernel thread there are some userland's thread associated with it.**

Comment: So are those user threads the node.js thread pool (I know node event loop is single threaded but it needs threads behind the scenes for everything else)? or those are created by the framework?

Comment: yeah...
those are the thread which node aplication uses to mainatain it's eventloop and every thing else...
by default every app has it's own several numbers of userland threads.which are created and controlled by the the app only.